# __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default(...)(...).metisMenu error

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, yarnpkg, metismenu

I already tried multiple things as deleting node_modules folder, installing everything with npm and with yarn. I added the dependency to the package.json

These are my dependencies:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
},
"dependencies": {
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "metismenu": "^3.0.0-alpha.2"
}
```

following is my app.js:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
global.jQuery = $;
require('jquery-slimscroll');
import 'metismenu';

/*
 *
 *   INSPINIA - Responsive Admin Theme
 *   version 2.7.1
 *
 */

$(document).ready(function () {


    // Add body-small class if window less than 768px
    if ($(this).width() < 769) {
        $('body').addClass('body-small')
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('body-small')
    }

    // MetsiMenu
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();

    // Collapse ibox function
    $('.collapse-link').on('click', function () {
        var ibox = $(this).closest('div.ibox');
        var button = $(this).find('i');
        var content = ibox.children('.ibox-content');
        content.slideToggle(200);
        button.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
        ibox.toggleClass('').toggleClass('border-bottom');
        setTimeout(function () {
            ibox.resize();
            ibox.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
        }, 50);
    });

    // Close ibox function
    $('.close-link').on('click', function () {
        var content = $(this).closest('div.ibox');
        content.remove();
    });

    // Fullscreen ibox function
    $('.fullscreen-link').on('click', function () {
        var ibox = $(this).closest('div.ibox');
        var button = $(this).find('i');
        $('body').toggleClass('fullscreen-ibox-mode');
        button.toggleClass('fa-expand').toggleClass('fa-compress');
        ibox.toggleClass('fullscreen');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(window).trigger('resize');
        }, 100);
    });

    // Minimalize menu
    $('.navbar-minimalize').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("body").toggleClass("mini-navbar");
        SmoothlyMenu();

    });

    // Full height of sidebar
    function fix_height() {
        var heightWithoutNavbar = $("body > #wrapper").height() - 61;
        $(".sidebard-panel").css("min-height", heightWithoutNavbar + "px");

        var navbarHeight = $('nav.navbar-default').height();
        var wrapperHeight = $('#page-wrapper').height();

        if (navbarHeight > wrapperHeight) {
            $('#page-wrapper').css("min-height", navbarHeight + "px");
        }

        if (navbarHeight < wrapperHeight) {
            $('#page-wrapper').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px");
        }

        if ($('body').hasClass('fixed-nav')) {
            if (navbarHeight > wrapperHeight) {
                $('#page-wrapper').css("min-height", navbarHeight + "px");
            } else {
                $('#page-wrapper').css("min-height", $(window).height() - 60 + "px");
            }
        }

    }

    fix_height();

    // Fixed Sidebar
    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        if ($("body").hasClass('fixed-sidebar')) {
            $('.sidebar-collapse').slimScroll({
                height: '100%',
                railOpacity: 0.9
            });
        }
    });

    $(window).bind("load resize scroll", function () {
        if (!$("body").hasClass('body-small')) {
            fix_height();
        }
    });

    // Add slimscroll to element
    $('.full-height-scroll').slimscroll({
        height: '100%'
    })
});


// Minimalize menu when screen is less than 768px
$(window).bind("resize", function () {
    if ($(this).width() < 769) {
        $('body').addClass('body-small')
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('body-small')
    }
});

function SmoothlyMenu() {
    if (!$('body').hasClass('mini-navbar') || $('body').hasClass('body-small')) {
        // Hide menu in order to smoothly turn on when maximize menu
        $('#side-menu').hide();
        // For smoothly turn on menu
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                $('#side-menu').fadeIn(400);
            }, 200);
    } else if ($('body').hasClass('fixed-sidebar')) {
        $('#side-menu').hide();
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                $('#side-menu').fadeIn(400);
            }, 100);
    } else {
        // Remove all inline style from jquery fadeIn function to reset menu state
        $('#side-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
}
```

i tried importing the package and requiring it. But the error still occurs.
This is the error i receive in my console (i am using Chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default(...)(...).metisMenu is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:106)
at mightThrow (app.js:3789)
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated!